# Android Studio (Kotlin) how to convert StringArray to MutableList

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get a `StringArray` from `Resources` and convert it into a [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html)

I tried the following code

`var morality = mutableListOf(activity.resources.getStringArray(R.string.morality))`

but it gives me an error saying

`Type mismatch 
Required: String? 
Found: ArrayOut<(out)String!>!`

Comment: it says found: MutableList<Array<(out)String!>!>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it with

```
var morality = (activity.resources.getStringArray(R.string.morality).toMutableList())
```

Comment: You could also use `mutableListOf(*activity.resources.getStringArray(R.string.morality))` (notice the `*`)

Comment: How to get String array like  resources.getStringArray(R.array.category) ?